# How to find number of votes cast using PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I have a PHP script which allows voting based on a login system.

I am trying to switch all the code to PDO instead of MySQL. I'm having trouble switching this particular piece of code. Here is the original:

```
$get_votes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE poll_id = 1 "); //select all votes to this poll

$votes = array(); //the array that will be containing all votes

$total_votes = 0;

while($vote = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_votes)) { //retrieve them
$answer_id = $vote['answer_id'];
$votes[$answer_id] = (int)$votes[$answer_id]+1; //add 1 vote for this particular answer
$total_votes++;
}


$get_answers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE poll_id = 1 ");

while($answer = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_answers)) { //loop through all answers

$id = $answer['id']; 
$width = round((int)$votes[$id]/$total_votes*99+1); //100%

echo ' This Answer has ('.(int)$votes[$id].' vote'.((int)$votes[$id] != 1 ? "s":"").')
   ';

}
```

What i would like to keep from this, is the `$width` and number of votes `$votes[$id]`. Whether it be a case of calculating all, from an Array or calculating individual answer results, if i supplied the answers variables.

I'm at a loose end here, i will have no hair left soon, so any suggestions/criticism is welcomed if it helps.

Comment: I don't really see the trying part here, when everything required is detailed in PHP's very own [PDO doc pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)...

Comment: where are the `while()` statement examples? this is what im struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM votes WHERE poll_id = :poll_id';
$params = array(':poll_id' => 1);
$stmt = $db->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute($params);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

Would be the very basic query/results converted to PDO (and that's just one way to do it in PDO). What exactly are you having problems with? The PDO documentation on the PHP site is pretty robust with lots of examples.

What have you tried? What isn't working? What unexpected behavior or errors are you getting? Need more information about what the actual problem is before any real answers can be given.

-- Edit from comment --

Your original code should work fine

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $answer_id = $row['answer_id'];
}
```

Should still work and you can go from there.

Comment: ok, the real things im having trouble with are getting the width variable and the number of votes that have been cast. everything like youve written i have done. as in prepared the connection etc. so really the `while()` parts

Comment: thanks! my code was a completely different way, but this seems alot clearer. I have converted it with an error however. It is not looping through and storing in array, any ideas why? its simply taking the last known vote and attributing only one vote.

Comment: No idea, you would need to update the question with the new code for people to see or else it's hard to know what the issue could be.

Comment: its fine, i had part of the code muddled. Your answer helped me alot, thanks